# NFS Mount keeps coming back after deleted

Tags: sles, nfsv4

I have an NFS mount that keeps coming back after I have deleted it from /etc/fstab and from YAST (SLES15 SP2).    I don't see any auto.fs or auto mounts and I don't know where this is coming from.   It's driving me nuts!!!.    FYI...When do a umount */directory* it works.... but then when go into YAST, it's there again.   Any ideas where else to look?

Answer (score 1):

Have you run `systemctl daemon-reload` after editing `/etc/fstab`?

In distributions that use `systemd`, `/etc/fstab` is parsed by `[/usr]/lib/systemd/system-generators/systemd-fstab-generator`, which will produce a set of `*.mount` and/or `*.automount` units for systemd.

If you edit `/etc/fstab`, in particular to remove an entry that has the `x-systemd.automount` option set, then the originally-created automount unit will still be present until you run `systemctl daemon-reload` or reboot the system.

See `systemctl list-units '*.automount'` to check for this condition.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...but it didn't work.    I made sure the fs was unmounted.  Double checked the /etc/fstab and made sure any entries were removed from YAST, but when I do a mount -a the darn thing comes back.   Scratching my head as to where it is getting the info to mount this from?

Comment: Do you have some sort of centralized configuration management system in place, like Ansible, SaltStack or similar? If so, that might be periodically checking and re-applying a centrally managed configuration, overriding your local changes. Or is the NFS mount part of a failover cluster configuration, like Pacemaker? If the mount is defined as part of a clustered service, the cluster manager might detect it's missing and "fix" it for you.